# NSNotification addObserver in two ViewControllers Swift

Tags: swift, nsnotifications

In my HomeViewController viewDidLoad method I have an observer that looks out for a new notification. When observed it segues to a SecondTableVC. I have an observer in the second VC looking for the same notification, but the second observer isn't seeing the notification and calling the method. Thanks in advance to anyone who can explain what I'm missing here? I removed the observer in both viewDidLoad and in the segue method, but it doesn't fix it.

```
var childVC: UIViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

childVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WordListsTableViewController")

// check for new notification - if there is segue to the SecondTableVC
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(HomeViewController.showChildVC), name: "NotificationActionPressed", object: nil) // Segue works fine.
        }

func showChildVC() {
    self.view.addSubview(childVC.view)
}
```

In SecondTableVC

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

// check for new notification - if there is 
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SecondTableVC.newNotif), name: "NotificationActionPressed", object: nil) 
    }

    func newNotif() {
        print("new notif") // THIS METHOD IS NOT GETTING CALLED 
    }
```

Comment: Is your `SecondTableVC` in memory, when the observer throws the notification to the subscribers?

Comment: its created after the segue

Comment: Hi - how do I get SecondTableVC into memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of piggybacking off of the answer from Phillip: If it is absolutely necessary that the second view controller listen to the NSNotification event, then the second view controller can be instantiated from the storyboard and held in memory by the first view controller until it needs to be displayed. In this case, the second view controller should subscribe to the notification event upon initialization.

Comment: Hi - the SecondTableVC does exist as its on screen and ViewDidLoad is being called. How do I instantiate it from storyboard and hold it in memory by the first VC until it is needed after the segue?

Comment: The `SecondTableVC` is created after the notification is posted. It exists, just not early enough. What you would need to do is create an instance of the storyboard that holds the second view controller and call `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(_:)` on it, then hold a reference to that view controller by making a property on your first view controller. Note that when you want to present the view controller, you will not be able to perform the segue because that will create a separate instance. You will have to present the view controller you are holding a reference to.

Comment: I tried the above edits, but don't understand how to create an instance of the storyboard that holds the second view controller? After all the app is being launched after the notification action anyway. That sounds like it needs to be done twice. There was me thinking that Notifications were a simple way to communicate between VCs and it turns out they can't listen unless they are all instantiated when the notification is sent. Humpf.

Comment: Yes, that is not a recommended method of passing data around an app. If you need to pass data to a view controller that is being presented with a segue, do so in the `prepareForSegue` method on the parent view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your segue causes the second view controller to be **created**.  If the segue is triggered by a notification, then the `SecondTableVC`'s `viewDidLoad` hasn't happened when the notification fires.

The second controller's not receiving the notification because it not only hasn't registered by that time, but doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Put some print statements into your code so that you see the order of things happening.  Either you're wrong about the notification triggering the segue or `SecondTableVC` does not exist **at the time of the notification**.